# Reemplazar con Excel VBA

Tags: excel

Hola tengo el siguiente código

```
    Private Function FiltraSexo(ByVal strTexto As String) As String

strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "M", "H")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "F", "M")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "Hombre", "H")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "Mujer", "M")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "Femenino", "M")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "Masculino", "H")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "hombre", "H")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "mujer", "M")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "femenino", "M")
strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "masculino", "H")
CURPFiltraSexo = UCase(strTexto)

End Function
```

Como podrán ver es una pequeña función para reemplazar el sexo de una persona, por solamente la letra H(Hombre) y M(Mujer).

En el caso que un usuario ingrese en una celda cualquiera de esas las palabras posibles deberá cambiar el valor, sin embargo quisiera saber si en Excel VBA hay algún objeto con el cual no importando la forma en que escribe el usuario la palabra, la función sepa reemplazar en automático el texto.

Les agradecería mucho su apoyo

Comment: Tu mejor opción es la validación de datos. Te evitarías muchos dolores de cabeza si fuerzas al usuario a que escriba H o M según corresponda, en vez de intentar pensar en tooooodas las formas posibles de escribir mal la palabra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función que genera la letra según el sexo puede ser así.

```
Public Function FiltraSexo(ByVal strTexto As String) As String
    Select Case strTexto
    Case "M"
        strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "M", "H")
    Case "F"
        strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "F", "M")
    Case "Hombre"
        strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "Hombre", "H")
    Case "Mujer"
        strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "Mujer", "M")
    Case "Femenino"
        strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "Femenino", "M")
    Case "Masculino"
        strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "Masculino", "H")
    Case "hombre"
        strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "hombre", "H")
    Case "mujer"
        strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "mujer", "M")
    Case "femenino"
        strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "femenino", "M")
    Case "masculino"
        strTexto = Replace(strTexto, "masculino", "H")
        
    End Select
    
    If strTexto = "H" Or strTexto = "M" Then
        FiltraSexo = strTexto
    End If
End Function
```

No es muy elegante, pero funciona, en realidad seria mucho mas fácil si haces una tabla en el mismo excel y luego usas `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` en VBA.

En el código de la hoja donde se debe aplicar esto, hay que poner el siguiente código.
click derecho en la pestaña del nombre de la hoja -> ver código.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sexo As String
    On Error GoTo casoerror
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    sexo = FiltraSexo(Target.Value)
    If sexo <> "" Then
        Target.Value = sexo
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
    
casoerror:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

De esta forma, cada vez que se realiza un cambio en la hoja, se ejecutara la función FiltraSexo, si esta devuelve algo, se pone el dato en la misma celda modificada.

Comment: No, de hecho tienes mucha razón, encontré que con select case es la mejor opción, pero para que no salga tan larga puedes hacer lo siguiente: ` Dim tmp As String
    tmp = LCase$(strTexto)
    Select Case tmp
        Case "femenino", "mujer", "f"
            FiltraSexo = "M"
        Case Is = "hombre", "masculino", "m"
            FiltraSexo = "H"
        
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Ingresa un sexo válido"`  y ya no se ve tan larga.

Comment: Exacto, eso esta mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Si bien estás considerando una lista de las posibles palabras, siempre pueden ocurrir errores en la escritura, como `Mjer` por ejemplo.

Por esta razón sugiero utilizar la validación de datos para poner límites a los valores aceptados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Haciendo esto, la función se limita a tomar la primera letra de la palabra.

Comment: Si esto es muy cierto muchas gracias. Lo que busco es hacer una función que no estés restringida a un libro al contrario que se puede llamar en cualquier libro y el usuario pueda seleccionar los datos o ponerlo en la sección de formula.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma de hacerlo por VBA es realizando un vlook (buscar) identificando sus iniciales es decir dejando una condicional y si cumple reemplace, es fácil solo se necesita de tres líneas de código, te aconsejo que lo hagas con un if y listo.